# Add a Class when In a certain Route - Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, ng-class

I'm trying to add a class when Im on a certain route. The code is in my AppComponent, Im using ngClass.

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `<a [ngClass]="getRoute(router)">
       // Some html code....
    })
```

and then I have the function on the same app.component.ts

```
  export class AppComponent  { 
    getRoute(){
     if (this.router.url === '/atendimento'){
      return "hide-bar";
   }
  }
 }
```

The error I'm getting is the following one:

> Property 'router' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

And yes, I am importing Routes, RouterModule and Router on the header. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html ?

Comment: Binding to a method this way is usually not a good idea. It will be called every time change detection runs and this is prone to harm the performance of your application. Rather update a field at appropriate events and bind to this field instead. Change detection is quite efficient with fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject the router

```
  export class AppComponent  { 

    constructor(private router:Router) {}

    getRoute(){
     if (this.router.url === '/atendimento'){
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gunter, I'll take note of your comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Please inject Router service in to your constructor.

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
export class AppComponent  { 
constructor(private router:Router){}
    getRoute(){
     if (this.router.url === '/atendimento'){
      return "hide-bar";
   }
  }
 }
```

@Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `
       // Some html code....
    })