# Angular - class assigned to component selector

Tags: angular, class, router

I'm using the router module to display my components. So before, in my root, I had

```html
<app-catalog class="column is-3"></app-catalog>
```

but now, as i'm using the router, I have

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

which is responsible for displaying the component depending on the url.

But what about the class that I used to have with my component ? How to attach this class to my component ? I tried to check if a `class` property would exist for its `@Component({})` but it seems that it does not :/

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301299/add-a-class-when-in-a-certain-route-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

You should use @HostBinding('class'). It can also be used conditionally. https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding

In your app-catalog.component.ts:

```
@HostBinding('class') class = 'column is-3';
```